# On a consequence of $G \mid I \iff \gcd(G, I) = G$ (Re: Odd Perfect Numbers and GCDs)

Tags: solution-verification, gcd-and-lcm, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

Let $N = q^k n^2$ be an [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) given in the so-called *Eulerian form*, where $q$ is the *special prime* satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.  Denote the *classical sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$ by $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$.

Consider the GCDs
$$G = \gcd\left(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2)\right)$$
$$H = \gcd\left(n^2,\sigma(n^2)\right)$$
$$I = \gcd\left(n,\sigma(n^2)\right).$$

It is known that
$$H = \frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k};$$
therefore, since $\gcd(q,n)=\gcd(q^k,\sigma(q^k))=1$ and $\sigma(n^2)$ is odd, then the above GCDs for $G$ and $I$ can be rewritten as
$$G = \gcd\left(\sigma(q^k)/2,H\right)$$
$$I = \gcd\left(n,H\right).$$

It is [known](https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.08116) that the identity
$$G \times H = I^2$$
is true, and that the divisibility constraint
$$G \mid I$$
holds.

Now, consider
$$\gcd(\sigma(q^k)/2,H)=G=\gcd(G,I)=\gcd\left(\gcd(\sigma(q^k)/2,H),\gcd(n,H)\right)=\gcd\left(\gcd(\sigma(q^k)/2,n),\gcd(H,H)\right),$$
where the last equality holds by [GCD Associative Property](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Greatest_Common_Divisor_is_Associative).  It follows that
$$\gcd(\sigma(q^k)/2,H)=G=\gcd\left(\gcd(\sigma(q^k)/2,n),H\right). \tag{1}$$
Equating GCD function arguments, we obtain
$$\sigma(q^k)/2=\gcd(\sigma(q^k)/2,n), \tag{2}$$
which is equivalent to $\sigma(q^k)/2 \mid n$.  But since $N = q^k n^2$ is (odd) perfect, then
$$\sigma(q^k)\sigma(n^2)=\sigma(q^k n^2)=\sigma(N)=2N=2q^k n^2$$
whence we obtain
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{n}=\frac{q^k n}{\sigma(q^k)/2};$$
hence, $n \mid \sigma(n^2)$ is also equivalent to $\sigma(q^k)/2 \mid n$.

To conclude, we have derived
$$G = \gcd\left(\sigma(q^k)/2,H\right) = \sigma(q^k)/2$$
and
$$I = \gcd\left(n,H\right) = n.$$

Here is my:

> **QUESTION:** Is the derivation of the step marked with a $(2)$ from the step marked with a $(1)$ above logically valid?  If not, how can it mended so as produce a correct proof?

Comment: If you presume $\,(H,A) = (H,B)\Rightarrow A=B$ then that is false, e.g. $(H,A) = (H,CA)\,$ when $(H,C)=1$ by Euclid. It's true iff $\!\bmod H\!:\ (A)=(B)\,$ i.e. $\,A\mid B\mid A\ \ $

Comment: Thank you for your time and attention, @BillDubuque!  Please write out your [last comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4605729/on-a-consequence-of-g-mid-i-iff-gcdg-i-g-re-odd-perfect-numbers-and?noredirect=1#comment9704514_4605729) as an actual answer, so that I can upvote, and so that this question does not remain in the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is copied verbatim from [Bill Dubuque's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4605729/on-a-consequence-of-g-mid-i-iff-gcdg-i-g-re-odd-perfect-numbers-and#comment9704514_4605729), so that this question does not remain in the unanswered queue.

---

Per [Bill Dubuque](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/242):

> If you presume $(H,A)=(H,B) \implies A=B$ then that is false, e.g. $(H,A)=(H,CA)$ when $(H,C)=1$ by Euclid. It's true iff mod $H$: $(A)=(B)$ i.e. $A \mid B \mid A$.